# Overflow hidden doesn't fill up entire height

Tags: html, css

My inner-divs have a background image which should be zooming in when you hover over it without the height and width of the div changing. I'm coming close but still the inner-div doesn't fill the full height of the outder-div. Unless you hover over it than the background image fills the entire height of the outer-div. This is because of the overflow:hidden I use I guess. Anyone knows how to fix this?

This is my HTML and CSS:

```css
.outer-div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-div {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

#port1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background-image: url(../img/desk.jpg);
}

.inner-div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div id="work" class="container border-bottom">
  <h1>My work</h1>
  <div class="portfolio outer-div">
    <div class="inner-div" id="port1">
      <h3>test</h3>
      <p>Website x</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio outer-div">
    <div class="inner-div" id="port2">
      <h3>test</h3>
      <p>project y</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio outer-div">
    <div class="inner-div" id="port3">
      <h3>test</h3>
      <p>Webapplicatie x</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio outer-div">
    <div class="inner-div" id="port4">
      <h3>test</h3>
      <p>Website y</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you describe the effect you want to achieve instead? I am not entirely sure `height: 100%` has any effect on your code at all, either that or your code snippet is incomplete. Just try to describe what you want to happen when the pointer hovers where, and do you want the content to transform with the background, for instance?

Comment: My idea is that the background image zooms in when you hover on it. But without  it becoming a bigger size. So that it zooms but instead of expanding the div in it's entirely just the image get zoomed in and the sides dissapear.

Comment: If you want to only zoom the background, then `transform` in current form won't do -- the entire element (`.inner-div`) is transformed, including its content.

Comment: But the real problem is that now (after adding overflow:hidden) that there's a whitespace from +/- 10 pixels above every inner-div even when I'm not hovering. And when I hover on it the div doesn't expand to the right, left or bottom, it only expands upwards since there's some whitespace which it can fill. So I just need to fill the entire inner-div with the background image even before I start hovering. Normally that's easy, but with a overflox:hidden it seems tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are witnessing a case of [collapsing margins in CSS](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing), an expected behavior.

Meaning that the top margin of your `.inner-div > h3` becomes the top margin of your `.inner-div` and the bottom margin of your `.inner-div > p` becomes the bottom margin of your `.inner-div` again.

Obviously, you didn't expect that, but fortunately margin collapsing is subject to a set of conditions.

One of the ways to do make sure margins do not collapse is to specify an `overflow` other than `visible` on the child element (`.inner-div` in your case) that participates in the parent-child margin collapsing behavior:

```
.inner-div {
    overflow: auto; /* Or 'hidden', depending on your preferences. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```css
.outer-div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-div {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

#port1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  transition: background-size 0.5s ease;
  background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ccc/fff&text=image);
}

#port1.inner-div:hover {
  /*transform: scale(1.2);*/
  background-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div id="work" class="container border-bottom">
  <h1>My work</h1>
  <div class="portfolio outer-div">
    <div class="inner-div" id="port1">
      <h3>test</h3>
      <p>Website x</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio outer-div">
    <div class="inner-div" id="port2">
      <h3>test</h3>
      <p>project y</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio outer-div">
    <div class="inner-div" id="port3">
      <h3>test</h3>
      <p>Webapplicatie x</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio outer-div">
    <div class="inner-div" id="port4">
      <h3>test</h3>
      <p>Website y</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried that yourself? `background-size` does not animate, although I can't give a good reason why -- it just does not appear to be supported by all the usual suspects, although it trivially should be.